# iOS: Adding UITapGestureRecognizer to container view intercepts UICollectionView's didSelectItemAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to my main `Content View` in my ViewController to dismiss my keyboard when the content view is tapped.

The problem is that I have a `UICollectionView` inside my content view, and setting the `UITapGestureRecognizer` intercepts the taps of my `UICollectionView`.

How do I allow my `UICollectionView`'s taps to go through so that the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method will fire again?

```
func setupGestureRecognizer() {
    let dismissKeyboardTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    contentView.addGestureRecognizer(dismissKeyboardTap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    contentView.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The way to solve this issue is by adding **`.cancelsTouchesInView = false`** to your `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

This allows touches inside other views to go through, such as a `UITableViewCell` touch.

```
func setupGestureRecognizer() {
    let dismissKeyboardTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    dismissKeyboardTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    contentView.addGestureRecognizer(dismissKeyboardTap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    contentView.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Hmm this is not working for me on Swift 4.2 iOS 12 :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

and remove your tapGesture.

Comment: This stops the interception of the `UICollectionView` but does not dismiss the keyboard when tapping anywhere on the screen.